# Azure pipeline msbuild succeds even with errors?

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines

So I was tasked with making a pipeline, that fails on any warnings. So i started raising them as errors using the "/warnaserror", it succesfully raises them as errors, but the build still succeds.

I've noticed that it succeeds only with the errors from the warnings, not from any other error.

The pipeline logs the errors.

Expected result: Build fails on any warning or error.

Actual result: Build succeeds with the warning raised as errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the msbuild property argument `TreatWarningsAsErrors=true` into msbuild task to break the process. That msbuild property could stop the build process.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the YAML and the log? Because it doesn't fail for me. Still succeeds